# Jupyter notebook freezing on a specific line of code

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

The code on its own works fine (the exact same thing did happen, although not as frequently), but once I threw my entire code in a giant loop, it seems on the second or third iteration, it gets stuck. I interrupt the kernel and the line on which it's stuck is:

```
gsigns[k] = np.sign((weights[0] * npoints[k].x) + (weights[1] * npoints[k].y))
```

gsigns is an array filled with zeros, and npoints a Numpy array. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: In each loop, are you modifying these arrays? For example, in the first iteration you have 4 elements, but in your second iteration you have something like 16? That may explain why it's hanging

Comment: It's always the exact same code with the same number of elements. The only change is that the numbers in the arrays are randomly generated.

Comment: Can you show the initialization code?  Without knowing exactly what each variable is it's impossible to tell.  You say `gsigns` is an array of zeros, do you mean a numpy array, a list, or something else?  Likewise, you say `npoints` is a numpy array, but a vanilla numpy array won't allow accessing attributes in that way.